# Trying to draw a graph from regular expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, regular-expressions

I do my homework
My regular expression is
$b^m\,(ab)^na | m,n >= 0$
After several attempts I have this:
[image]

The vertex q1 is the entry and q2 is the exit.
Do you think it corresponds to the given regular expression ?

Comment: Looks right to me, if by "exit" you mean $q_2$ is the accepting state.

Comment: Thank you ! @Karl